# Break symbolic eigenvalue calculation early

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, linear-algebra, symbolic, eigenvalues

I am computing eigenvalues of matrices with single monomial entries (x,y,z, etc.) and for efficiency, need to truncate calculations early if any eigenvalues contain non-linear (x^{2}, \sqrt(x),x*y etc.) terms with respect to its entries. The entries are symbolic and not assigned any value.

I am currently using Eigenvalues[], and assume I would have to modify the code for this built-in method. Maybe there is a way to separate screening for non-linear terms and an exact calculation for speed-up, or find a way to apply numerical eigenvalue solvers?

Comment: Could compute the characteristic polynomial and factor it. Any factors that contain variables and are nonlinear will have the type of roots you are trying to avoid.

Comment: could you give an example of input and expected output?

Comment: Factoring the characteristic polynomial is about as fast as Eigenvalues[], but if you can check whether it contains any factors with powers other than 1 (without doing the entire factorization) it would solve this issue.

Comment: Sure, if I have two matrices $A=\begin{pmatrix} x & 0 \\ 0 & y \end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix} x & y \\ z & x \end{pmatrix}$, I would output the eigenvalues of A, and break on B because its eigenvalues are $x \pm \sqrt{y}\sqrt{z}$. Its characteristic polynomial contains a second-order factor. The matrices could be larger which would make breaking early on B more practical than this example.